# lambda proxy integration cognitoIdentityId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to get the cognitoIdentityId when using lambda proxy integration?

event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId is always null and can't use request mapping templates because of proxy integration.

I am using AWS amplify where I can retrieve the identityId but I don't want to trust the client to pass me this info.

Do I have to disable lambda proxy integration to achieve this?